# Select specific column from specific row (Python - MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql

So I'm not so experienced in Python, but I really enjoy making stuff with it.
I decided to start using Python to interact with MySQL in one of my projects.

I would like to write a function that takes the username as input and returns the password as output.

Here is what I've tried to do:

```
def get_passwd(user_name):
    user_passwd = mycursor.execute("SELECT passwd FROM users WHERE name = '%s'", (user_name))
    print(user_passwd)

get_passwd("Jacob")
```

But it's justing printing out "None".

My table looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear which package you are using to access your database.
Assuming it is sqlalchemy what you are missing is the fetch command.

So you should add -

```
def get_passwd(user_name):
    user_passwd = mycursor.execute("SELECT passwd FROM users WHERE name = '%s'", (user_name))
    user_actual_passwd = user_passwd.fetchone()
    print(user_actual_passwd)
get_passwd("Jacob")
```

See more [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html)

** Update as the question was updated **

I would make sure that the query strings is what you are expecting. 
Do -

```
query = "SELECT passwd FROM users WHERE name = '%s'", (user_name)
print (query)
```

If the query is what you are expecting, try running it directly on the db and see if you get any result.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot that part. I'm using mysql.connector and I tried to add fetchone() command, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
user_passwd = mycursor.execute("SELECT passwd FROM users WHERE name = '%s'", (user_name))
```

use something as

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT passwd FROM users WHERE name = '%s'", (user_name))
row = mycursor.fetchone()

user_passwd = row[0]
```

Comment: That also returns None

Comment: It probably means that your table `users` don't have a record with `Jacob` in the `passwd` field.

Comment: Btw I see that your password is a number, not a string. Little weird.

Comment: You table has only 1 record, so try change your SELECT statement - trim out the whole WHERE clause.

Comment: But the problem is in this line: ```user_passwd = mycursor.execute("SELECT passwd FROM users WHERE name = '%s'", (user_name))```. Because I can return ```9310``` with ```user_passwd = mycursor.execute("SELECT passwd FROM users WHERE name = 'Jacob'")```